# Is the possible Bell's test loophole of entangled particles communicating at a non instantaneous but FTL speed addressed and eliminated?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality, non-locality, epr-experiment

**TLDR**:

1. There seems to be a loophole in Bell's test that is not addressed or eliminated before we can successfully conclude that it proves that the Universe is unreal and non local. The entangled particles can still communicate at a non instantaneous but FTL speed. I'm unable to find any reference for such a loophole on the intenret. Is this loophole acknowledged and eliminated?
2. What happens if we perform the Modified Bell Test by Electromagnetic Isolation (MoBeTEIs) experiment mentioned below? What are the consequences of two different outcomes?

Please answer the above two questions pointwise separately to be more clear and avoid confusion. The rest of the post is about me explaining the background and why I think the question is valid.

---

This is in the light of recent [Nobel prize](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/2022/press-release/) given to physicists

> for experiments with entangled photons, establishing the violation of
> Bell inequalities and pioneering quantum information science

The [claim](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-universe-is-not-locally-real-and-the-physics-nobel-prize-winners-proved-it/) is that they have conclusively proven that the result of Bell's test and the resulting
violation of Bell inequalities confrims that the Universe is not locally real, by closing all the [plausible loopholes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_test#Loopholes)  except [superdeterminism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdeterminism), which in general, is

> fundamentally untestable, as the correlations can be
> postulated to exist since the Big Bang, making the loophole impossible to eliminate.

Another important loophole was the locality loophole where there was a possibility for the entangled particles to communicate at the speed of light. This was eliminated by using long distances between measurements of entangled particles, where both the measurements were made within the narrow timeframe shorter than the time required by light to travel between the two places.

---

But, there seems to be another loophole which I'm not able to find being  accounted for or being discussed.

There is still a possibility of non instantaneous but faster than light(FTL) signalling between the entangled particles.

FTL travel is not completely unproven, We already know Einstein's theory of relativity [is at odds](https://www.thetribune.ca/sci-tech/the-universe-at-odds-quantum-mechanics-versus-general-relativity040418/) with quantum mechanics and his general theory of relativity is [incomplete](https://www.einstein-online.info/en/explandict/singularity/#:%7E:text=The%20occurrence%20of%20singularities%20is,a%20theory%20of%20quantum%20gravity.) as it melts down at singularity in blackholes and at the beginning of the Universe.

Given this, it seems rather interesting that important features of quantum mechanics - non locality and unrealism, is proven assuming that the thoery of relativity is absolutely true, when we know that the latter is incomplete and [is in odds with](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2015/nov/04/relativity-quantum-mechanics-universe-physicists) the very thing it is being used to prove.

The possibility of non-instantaneous but FTL signalling seems far more tenable and intutive rather than Universe being non-local and unreal. And therefore this seems to be a loophole for Bell's test.

---

This loophole may be non falsifiable if the signalling is too weak a force to detect. But it is possible to block the signalling given that the entangled particles are using a force which is susceptible to shielding.

There are four known forces of nature:

[image]
[Image Credit](https://www.embibe.com/exams/fundamental-forces-of-nature/)

The strong and weak nuclear forces can be excluded as it is short range acting.

Gravitational influence or force, as of now, cannot be shielded and [gravitational shielding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_shielding) is still a hypothetical concept. So if the entangled particles are using gravitational force to interact, then as of now it is impossible to test it.

But given that electrons are charged particles and photons are electromagnetic in nature, it is more probable that if at all the entangled electrons and photons interact they possibly interact using electromagnetic interaction which can be shielded using [electromagnetic shielding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding) and [lead shielding.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_shielding)

Regarding electromagnetic force travelling only at speed of light, it is still thoeretically possible for electromagnetic force to travel FTL, if the space between entangled particles itself is stretched and snaps when the measurement is made just like [the diameter of the Universe(46.1 billion light years) is larger than the age of the Universe(13.8 billion years)](https://bigthink.com/starts-with-a-bang/universe-speed-of-light/) and like [shock wave in air moving at faster speed than sound](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/193323/365056).

---

**Modified Bell Test by Electromagnetic Isolation(MoBeTEIs) Experimental Setup**:

This modified Bell test would have one extra feature of isolating measurement devices within a globe which can shield from electromagnetic force.

Initially entangled particles are created and sent to two measuring devices which are kept inside electromagnetic shielding globes with gates open, so as to let the electrons get inside.

[image]

Once the entangled particle enters the globe, **before it is measured, the gates of the globe needs to be closed** so as to not either let out or let in any electromagnetic signals.

[image]

There are two possible outcomes for this experiment and I think the following are the ramifications of the respective outcomes of the experiment.

1. **Bell equality is still violated in MoBeTEIs**, which maintains status quo assumption but we also know that entangled particles used in MoBeTEIs does not communicate using electromagnetic signals.
2. **Bell equality is not violated in MoBeTEIs**, proves the Universe to be local and real and also favours hidden variable theories. There will be huge ramifications to Copenhagen and Many worlds interpretation. The possibility FTL signalling will be confirmed.

What do you think happens if we actually perform the MoBeTEIs experiment? What would the different results mean according to you?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/746135/how-does-bells-theorem-disprove-realism/746167#746167

Comment: I don't how this is not mainstream physics. I'm literally asking a historical question and a prediction quesion. 1) Is this loophole accounted for? 2) What happens if we perform the experiment? That's the question. Please restore the question.

Comment: @HariKumar If you want to have a discussion about the on-topicness of this question, feel free to ask a question on [Physics Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Chris-RegenerateResponse thank yoy

Comment: Experiments have shown that if there are FTL influences, they must be at least 10,000 times the speed of light. https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0614

Comment: @DrChinese thank you.

Answer (score 9):

The word "loophole" is often thrown around in an imprecise way when it comes to Bell Experiments, but  no matter how you define the term, any faster-than-light influence is *not* a "loophole".

[Bell's argument](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.92.021002) is a proof by contradiction.  The argument begins by assuming two things: (1) there is no faster than light influence, and (2) the future settings are uncorrelated with any past hidden variables relevant to the eventual outcomes.  Given those assumptions, it proves an inequality, which is violated by experiment.  Therefore at least one of the assumptions (1) or (2) must be wrong.  That's the conclusion.

Positing that "maybe there are faster than light influences" is not a loophole, it's simply one of the possible conclusions of the above argument.  Any such argument would be in agreement that (1) is false, which is the *standard* conclusion of Bell's argument, not anything new.

A true "loophole" is something that would allow both (1) and (2) to be true, despite Bell's Theorem and the experiments.  For example, the [detection efficiency loophole](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.220402) (now closed) used to be able to argue that (1) and (2) might still both be true.

Comment: If that was the case then the conclusion should not be that local realism is false. The conclusion should have been either FTL signalling and hidden variables are possible or Copenhagen interpretation is true. But no one is saying that, everyone is saying that it is proven that universe is non local and hidden variable theories are false.

Comment: Look at these sources

Comment: The Universe Is Not Locally Real, and the Physics Nobel Prize Winners Proved It Source: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-universe-is-not-locally-real-and-the-physics-nobel-prize-winners-proved-it/

Comment: There are no local hidden variable theories compatible with quantum mechanics. Source: https://bigthink.com/13-8/quantum-entanglement-hidden-variable/

Comment: The standard takeaway is that locality — that long-held assumption about physical law — is not a feature of our world. Source: https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-bells-theorem-proved-spooky-action-at-a-distance-is-real-20210720/

Comment: Bell called the conjunction of assumptions (1) and (2) "local realism" in some papers and "local causality" in others.  So the Bell experiments prove that nature 'violates local realism' or 'violates local causality', depending on which of Bell's phrases you use as a stand-in for his formal assumptions.  It's unfortunately common these days to lazily drop Bell's second word and just say that nature 'violates locality'.  But without the context of the formal assumptions (1) and (2), these phrases can't be properly interpreted.

Comment: When physicists say that Bell experiments show there are no hidden variables, they should always be clear that they mean that these experiments can't be explained by any hidden variable model which conforms to both (1) and (2).  Of course there are non-local hidden variable models (say, Bohmian mechanics) which violate (1), and you can have retrocausal hidden variable theories which violate (2).   Any FTL model would violate (1), instantaneous or not.

Comment: I have three points. Please answer them point by point to avoid confusion. 1) Again in your comments you say non local hidden variable models like Bohmian mechanics. Here what do you mean by non local??  FTL?? Or remote instantaneous influence?? Which one do you mean by the word non local?

Comment: 2)Ok this makes sense. Can you please provide some links where Bell argues 1. and 2. Assunptions makes it local realism? Also, I don't know why reputed jouranls are just throwing around the word locality when they mean FTL is not possible. **Something can be FTL and still be absolutely local**

Comment: 3) But your answer still doesn't answer the main intention of the question. Let's say we performed this new experiment I suggested. Now there are two possibilities 1. Bell equalities are still violated. 2. Bell equalities are not violated. Now what would be oir conclusion for these two experimental outcomes?? Do we already have that data?? What happens if we perform this experiment??

Comment: On 1):  There are two uses of 'locality' in these arguments, two ways a theory can be nonlocal.  One applies to the ontology; are fundamental things which the theory describes "localized" in space and time?  Electric fields are "local beables" in Bell's terminology, while a quantum wavefunction is not a "local beable".  Then, there is the question of whether the theory/model describes "local" interactions or not, meaning that influences are mediated by lightspeed (or slower) mediators.   Any faster-than-light influence (mediated or not) is then considered "nonlocal".

Comment: On 2). See my response to 1).  Some quotes and links to Bell's writing on this topic, in context, can be found here: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bell%27s_theorem#Bell.27s_definition_of_locality .  On 3) the experiment has not been done, but FTL interactions could not be electromagnetic (to the extent that we understand EM).  We couldn't be sure that any "new sort" of FTL "EM" wave would be blocked by the same things that block regular lightspeed EM waves.

Comment: so you are saying if we conduct this experiment, the Bell inequalities will be still violated?

Comment: If you consider that the Himalaya mountains would act like a barrier to these magical FTL EM waves, then the best place to look for experimental results would be the entangled pairs sent down from a satellite to two distant measurement stations: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/china-shatters-ldquo-spooky-action-at-a-distance-rdquo-record-preps-for-quantum-internet/ .  Yes, the inequalities were still violated.

Comment: Thank you @KenWharton

Comment: Now it is narrowed down to gravitational waves. There's still a possiblity of FTL gravitational waves being used to signal between the particles. Gravitational waves cannot be shielded like EM waves. So may be that's possible.

Answer (score -1):

> There seems to be a loophole in Bell's test that is not addressed or eliminated before we can successfully conclude that it proves that the Universe is unreal and non local.

It doesn't prove the universe is non-realist or non-local. There is another interpretation of quantum mechanics consistent with Bell's test, that is local, realist, and deterministic: the Everett Interpretation, also known as the Many Worlds Interpretation.

'Realism' isn't about saying "the universe is unreal". Realism is about whether *the wavefunction* is real. Does the wavefunction constitute the actual true state of reality in between measurements, or is it just mathematics? The wavefunction seems to describe alternative things that *could* happen, but *don't* - what philosophers call *counterfactuals*.

We stare at our opponent across the poker table and wonder if he is holding the ace of spades in his hand. In our head, there is a probability distribution describing different branches, in some of which he does, and in others he doesn't, but only *one* of them will turn out to be real - to have a mind-independent existence. Our probability calculations *work*, but the alternative scenarios they are describing aren't real, they only exist in our minds.

Quantum mechanics seems to be saying that these alternative possibilities *are* real. The alternative paths *interfere* with one another. Does the wavefunction have a mind-independent existence, even when it is not being observed? Do complementary properties like position and momentum exist, before they are observed? The idea that these are real and meaningful, and not just imaginary artefacts of the mathematics, is called *Realism*.

But this seemingly runs headlong into the obvious fact that we see only one outcome. Where do all the others go?

One way out of the problem is to retreat to what we can see - to say that the only reality is *what is observed*, that reality jumps from one observation to the next, with nothing in between, and the observations follow statistical patterns *as if* there were these interfering wavefunctions in between them, but they shouldn't be taken seriously as a description of reality. Statements about things we cannot observe are scientifically meaningless. We simply don't know, and possibly never will.

This point of view is sometimes called the "Shut up and calculate" school. As Einstein put it to a colleague who followed this school: "Do you really believe that the moon isn't there when nobody looks?"

Another approach is to say the wavefunction is real, but *collapses* to a definite value when observed. This is the mainstream Copenhagen Interpretation, and what Bell assumed.

A third approach is to say the wavefunction is real and doesn't collapse. What happens is that the observer is a wavefunction too, and when the observer interacts with the particle, their wavefunctions become *correlated*. A particle in a superposition of possible outcomes results in an observer in a superposition of observers observing all those possible outcomes. The components of a linear superposition do not interact with one another (just as the superposed components of an electron's wavefunction do not repel one another), which is why we seem to see only one outcome. And because all the alternative outcomes are still around, the correlations can be explained when widely-separated entangled observers meet up to compare notes.

This third approach is thus consistent with the outcome of Bell's test, and is local, realist, and deterministic. It does, on the other hand imply the existence of a possibly-infinite number of unobservable entities!

> The entangled particles can still communicate at a non instantaneous but FTL speed.

This doesn't work because in Special Relativity, 'instantaneous' depends on your reference frame. When two events A and B are simultaneous according to one observer, another observer moving past him in one direction will see A happen before B, and a different observer moving in the opposite direction will see B happen before A.

So for any pair of spacelike-separated events, there is *some* reference frame in which they are simultaneous, and *some* reference frame where the effect occurs before its cause.

Any effect that propagates faster than light will, to some relatively-moving observers, also propagate backwards in time.

This is a *necessary* consequence if the wavefunction collapses - the propagating collapse is a *genuine* change of the actual state of the universe, by realism, and will propagate backwards in time according to some observers, by relativity. Because there is an alternative interpretation of the observations that is local, we can be certain that there is no way to use this to communicate faster than light. All the parts that propagate faster than light are unobservable. It is the counterfactuals - the alternative outcomes that didn't happen - magically vanishing! According to some observers, they vanish even before the observation that made them vanish actually happens!!

But since this is an argument about matters that can never be experimentally tested, it's not science. It is philosophy, or metaphysics, or aesthetics. You can only pick an interpretation based on criteria like which is simpler, more elegant, more 'explanatory', more intuitively acceptable, or easier to calculate with.

Comment: This is interesting. But it has nothing to do with the question. It is a non answer bit great information. Also Everett interpretation is still non local. I don't know why you are claiming it as local. There is still correlation in measurement between entangled particles, that is to be explained.

Comment: The answer to your question is in the second half of my answer - yes, it has been considered; special relativity means there's no such thing as FTL but not instantaneous. The first half of my answer was really just a side-note to explain why the premise of the question is wrong. There *is* a local, realist, deterministic interpretation, fully consistent with Bell's correlations. The Everett Interpretation *is* local, and *does* explain the correlations. It is just the ordinary unitary evolution of the wavefunction, which the relativistic Schrodinger equation *requires* to be local.

Comment: Hmm I think you missed my question. My question is calling the assumption of special theory of relativity being true into question. You can't answer this just by saying because of special theory of relativity says so. More over I have given the example of Universe being larger than if it had travelled at speed of light, as space itself is expanding. You missed it. Also you say it is considered, can you olease back it up with the source. I don't think it's considered. Also you keep saying Everett's interpretation ia local while it is not. Can you please explain how it explains the correlation?

Comment: Source which says Many world's is non local https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.07794

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/371543589_An_Elementary_Proof_That_Everett's_Quantum_Multiverse_Is_Nonlocal_Bell-Locality_and_Branch-Symmetry_in_the_Many-Worlds_Interpretation

Comment: Oh, OK. If you're proposing Special Relativity is *wrong*, then we're well outside mainstream physics and anything goes. That's usually considered off-topic for this site. The Everett Interpretation is just ordinary unitary quantum mechanics, without collapse. It is precisely the theory that *predicts* the correlations. It's too involved to explain in comments - I'd suggest reading Everett's thesis https://cqi.inf.usi.ch/qic/everett_phd.pdf and ask another question if you have to. I think the paper you cite is misinterpreting Everett, but I don't find their explanation very clear.

Comment: The word "Realism" can mean a range of different things in different contexts, but when discussing Bell's theorem Realism refers specifically to whether the *measured values* are real physical quantities that exist independent of measurement. People will sometimes talk about "Realism in the sense of Bell" or "Bell Realism" to make this point clear. Bell Realism specifically does *not* make any claims either way about the whether the wavefunction is real or not and the Everett interpretation is not Reallist in this sense.

Comment: Yes, the wavefunction is the summary of all the 'measured values'. The wavefunction can be represented in terms of a basis of paired eigenstates and eigenvalues, corresponding to each possible 'measured value', but this is just a coordinate system for expressing the wavefunction. Have you read Everett's thesis?

Comment: This paper by Deutch and Hayden may also be useful. https://arxiv.org/ftp/quant-ph/papers/9906/9906007.pdf

Comment: The paper I jave referred is from arxiv which is reputable. I'm not the one who is referring that theory of relativotoy is wrong. Everyone agrees that it is wrong in the semse it is incomplete. Did you read the part of the question where I addressed how theory of relativoty is at odds with quantum physics. Every physicist agress that theory of relativoty is incomplete. Also you completely ignored me pointing out that universe is 40+ billion light years wide when it's only 13+ bilion years old. How is this possible?? In the same way "FTL" communication between entangled particles are possible.

Comment: Also Everett's model cannot account for correlation in spin between entangled electrons if it is local. I don't know why you keep arguig it. Please explain how it explains Bell's test while being a local model. Or link something specific to it explaining it.

Comment: The wavefunction contains information about all possible outcomes, but the question is about the single value that you measure in a given run of the experiment. It is about whether the electron has a single, well defined position before we measure it. To be more precise, Bell  Realism is the statement that we can assign a value to a measurement we did not  make that we would have measured had we made that measurement.

Comment: @HariKumar The Everett interpretation states that the equations of motion of quantum physics are an accurate description of how the reality works. It states that each system exists in multiple versions and on the large scale to a good approximation those versions are sorted by local interactions into layers each of which looks like the universe as described by classical physics https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033 In the specific case of the Bell experiment this means the correlations don't exist until the results are compared, as explained in the paper linked above.